# no logramos imprimir imagen en modal con php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estamos realizando un sistema web de inscripción de mascotas, al momento de llegar al módulo de administración se tiene que aprobar la inscripción de dicha mascota, en tal sentido al dar clic en ver se debe de desplegar un modal bootstrap, con todos los datos ingresados desde el frontend, lo que hasta ahora no logramos es imprimir la foto de la mascota en el modal, les pedimos nos ayuden, gracias

Codigo HTML

```
<div class="col-4 tamaimagen">
     <img src="../../../fotos/" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail" id="fotoMascota">
</div>

<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modalRegitra" onclick="agregarEstado('<?php echo $datos; ?>')">Ver</button></td>
```

Codigo PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT s.idsolicitud, s.nombre_propietario, s.apellidos_propietario, s.correo, s.idtipo_doc, td.tipodoc, s.numero_documento, s.telefono_fijo, s.celular, s.direccion,
                s.nombre_mascota, s.fecha_nac_mascota, s.idSexo, s.idesterelizado, s.idraza, s.color_mascota, s.foto_mascota, s.fecha, s.descrip_raza_varios, s.idestado, s.observaciones
                FROM solicitud s
                INNER JOIN tipo_doc td ON s.idtipo_doc = td.idtipo_doc";
                $query = $conexion->query($sql);
                while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $datos =                              
                        $valores['direccion'] .
                        "||" .
                        $valores['foto_mascota']; ?>
```

Codigo Jquery

```
       function agregarEstado(datos) {           
        $("#direccionPropietario").val(d[7]);
        $("#fotoMascota").val(d[8]);  
       }
```

Comment: funciona sin ajax ?

Comment: Te comento todo el formularios funciona, solo es el problema de la imagen, la parecer el problema es con la ruta de la imagen que no se como hacerlo funcionar..

Comment: y la imagen si esta guardada en la ruta que estas indicando?

Comment: acabo de poner la ruta, espero me ayuden, la verdad que no encuentro, solucion..

Comment: `img src="../../../fotos/ejemplo.jpg"` y el nombre de la imagen por que no esta ?

Comment: no esta por que tiene que ser dinámico, quiere decir que que al momento de dar click en el botón ver se debe de desplegar un modal con toda la información de la mascota incluido la foto..

Comment: `$("#fotoMascota").val(d[8]); ` .val es usado para asignar datos a un input tu estas usando una etiqueta imagen

Comment: Exactamente, lo que pasa que no se como hacerlo para una imagen te agradecería me ayudes, gracias

Comment: `$("#fotoMascota").attr("src","fotos/ejemplo.jpg");` asi se asigna a una imagen

Comment: y como saco ejemplo.jpg ya que eso seria la foto de una mascota cualquiera, lo que quiero es al dar click en ver me debe de salir la imagen de esa mascota.

Comment: `d[8]` esto si esta trayendo los datos ?

Comment: como lo los uno para que aparezca la foto

Comment: en caso de que tu variable contenga la ruta solo seria colocar `$("#fotoMascota").attr("src",d[8]);`

Comment: pero no te puedo decir que ruta contiene d[8] seria bueno que mostraras lo que contiene esa variable con alert

Comment: d[8], tiene el nombre de la imagen o foto de la mascota, lo que  me gustaría me expliques como obtengo la ruta y luego unirlo con el nombre de la imagen, ejemplo d[8] almacena 1.pg.

Comment: si tiene el nombre de la imagen solo debes colocar algo mas o menos asi. `$("#fotoMascota").attr("src","../../../fotos/"+d[8]);`

Comment: Amigo, muchísimas gracias, muy agradecido..

Comment: la ruta la colocas tu ya que solo estas guardando el nombre de la imagen